# Java Swing Custom Layout Issue

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm having trouble organizing the contents of a JPanel. I've tried different layout managers but haven't gotten anything to work.

The JPanel contains 3 other JPanels and should look like this:

[image: Desired Layout]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is similar to a `BorderLayout`, but using one natively will cause the second pane to fill the bottom space (rather than the 3rd pane.)

However, you could use two in tandem to get this effect - The first `BorderLayout` pane would contain the second `BorderLayout` pane (in its centre) and panel 3 (on its east.)

In the second `BorderLayout` pane, you could then just set pane 1 to be the centre, and pane 2 to be the south.

Comment: Thanks. I'm somewhat new to Swing and didn't know a BorderLayout even existed!

Comment: @ama291 No problem, it might be worth familiarising yourself with the basic layout managers here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

Simplest, but not best solution, is to use null Layout Manager with manually set components bounds. It is called [Absolute Positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

Other approach is to use horizontal [SplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) with nested Vertical SplitPane: left one will contain vertical splitPane with Panel1 and Panel2, and right will be just Panel3.